# Which Nazca line figure is this?

Tags: identify-this, peru

We flew over the Nazca lines last month.
I'm currently organizing my pictures and I don't recognize this one:

[image]

[image]

Which figure is this?

Comment: Do you have coincidentally the coordinates?

Comment: Which lines did you see before and after of this?

Comment: @ThorstenS. No, sorry

Comment: @artptr Before: heron. After: parrot. (if the order of my pictures is still intact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I found it: https://www.google.com/maps/@-14.6854788,-75.1105134,200m/data=!3m1!1e3 (looks a little more quality on Bing, but I don't know how to get a link). The Parrot is to South-East from it. The Heron Bird is very poorly visible to North-West.

[image: The figure]

The most full map of lines that I found is [image: Nazca lines map]

On this map Alcatraz Heron Bird named as Flamingo, and your figure named as Frigate Bird.

BTW, I surprised at several points:

1. I don't know why a two-circled figure near the bird's tale isn't present on aerial photos.
2. I didn't find any official and accurate lines map. Google and Bing maps don't provide the Nazca area in details too.

Comment: Thank you; definitely the frigate bird. [Look here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/231582239_fig2_Figure-3-The-Nazca-Frigatebird-His-bill-was-pointed-towards-the-setting-of-Fomalhaut-in) or [here](http://wikimapia.org/22282881/Nazca-Frigate-Bird)

Comment: You say *two-circled figure near the bird's tale*. But what if it's the other way around and that's actually the head? I also haven't found a photo yet where that is visible.